# Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_xmlrpc.dll'

Tags: apache2, php, php7

I have installed Apache 2.4, PHP7, and installed SimpleXML using:

```
apt-get install php-simplexml
```

Then I uncommented the line in `php.ini` for `extension=php_xmlrpc.dll` and restarted Apache.

My `apache.log` tells me this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_xmlrpc.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_xmlrpc.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

How do I get this to go away?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have 2 issues with what you described.

First, you installed a module (`simplexml`), while you are trying to enable a different one (`xmlrpc`).

To fix that, you need to install the `xmlrpc` module with:

```
sudo apt install php-xmlrpc
```

The second issue is the fact that you are trying to enable a `.dll` which is somewhat exclusive to Windows systems. On *nix systems, PHP extensions are usually `.so`.

But in either case, when you need to enable PHP packages in Ubuntu, you should use the `phpenmod` command (Available after 14.04).

So you should revert your changes by commenting that line, and run the following command:

```
sudo phpenmod xmlrpc
```

Comment: I actually thought the .dll was odd- but I found more than one set of instructions that told me to do each of these steps. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

DLL is a dynamic link library file format used for holding multiple codes and procedures for Windows programs. DLL files were created so that multiple programs could use their information at the same time, aiding memory conservation.

Please comment the line you've uncommented because DLL is for Windows. Ubuntu doesn't find files with extension *.dll.